Logic of login and register using react and firebase not redirecting properly after implementation
I have been trying to run the logic of login and register using react and firebase, but upon clicking login or register, I am navigated to the directed page in the code, but it is inaccessible and I have to refresh the page to use it.
Function for Login form and to handle login upon clicking submit button
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, app } from "../../pages/firebaseConfig";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

function LoginForm() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate("");

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((UserCredential) => {
        navigate("/About");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

HTML for the Login form
return (
    <form id="form-signin" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="email-signin" className="form-label">
          Email address
        </label>
        <input
          type="email"
          className="form-control"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          name="email-signin"
          aria-describedby="emailHelp"
          id="email-signin"
        />
        <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">
          We'll never share your email with anyone else.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="password-signin" className="form-label">
          Password
        </label>
        <input
          type="password"
          className="form-control"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          name="password-signin"
          id="password-signin"
        />
      </div>

      <div className="mb-3">
        <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            className="custom-control-input"
            id="customCheck1"
          />
          <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customCheck1">
            Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="btn btn-primary"
        id="button-signin"
        value="Login"
      >
        Log In
      </button>
      <p className="forgot-password text-right">
        Forgot <a href="#">password?</a>
      </p>
    </form>
  );
}

Login form where I enter the credentials and click Login button
I am being navigated, but the page is unresponsive unless i refresh the page
Upon refreshing the page, it is accessible
